connection was closed in FCM Legacy push message
when i send push notification, facing issue messages are undelivered and connection was closed.
we need to fix the connection was closed issue fix.some time i am getting not yet implemented Error.
why it is failing with connection was closed error?.
we are tried with notification payload and need to save
